# как задать событие onClick по всему компоненту, в том числе и по нажатию на содержимое

Tags: javascript, reactjs

По нажатию на компонент меняются стили, в этом компоненте есть другие кастомные компоненты которые занимают какое-то место в нем, соответственно по нажатию на часть компонента, поверх которой другой кастомный компонент компонент событие не срабатывает, как можно вызывать событие по нажатию на любую область?

```js
const CardPrice = (props) => {
return(
<div className='price-div'>
    <h2>{props.name}</h2>
    <h1>{props.cost}</h1>
</div>)
}
const PurchaseButton = () => {
return (
    <div className='button-div'>
        <div className='bgCLip'>
        <button className='button-buy' >buy now</button>
        </div>
    </div>)
 }

const Card = () => {
  const [divActive, setDivActive] = React.useState("");

  const changeClass = (el) => {
    setDivActive(el.target.id); 
  }
        
  return(
    <div className='general-div'>
      <div 
        className={`price-card first ${divActive === '1' ? 'price-card__active' : "" } `}
        id='1' 
        onClick={changeClass}
      >
        <CardPrice name={'eco'} cost={'﹩14.99'} />
        <PurchaseButton />
      </div>

      <div 
        className={`price-card second ${divActive === '2' ? 'price-card__active' : "" } `}
        id='2' 
        onClick={changeClass}
      >
        <CardPrice name={'next'} cost={'﹩19.99'} />
        <PurchaseButton />
      </div>

      <div 
        className={`price-card third ${divActive === '3' ? 'price-card__active' : "" } `}
        id='3' 
        onClick={changeClass}
      >
        <CardPrice name={'business'} cost={'﹩24.99'} />
        <PurchaseButton />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Card />
);
```

```css
.general-div{
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .price-card{
        width: 250px;
        height: 350px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(white ,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.806));
        box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        transition: 0.3s;
        border-radius: 8px;
        margin: 10px;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .price-card__active {
        background-image: linear-gradient(-235deg, rgba(151, 154, 196, 0.767) 5%, rgba(46, 20, 152, 0.807));
        border-radius: 12px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        transform:scale(1.04);
        scale: 1.02;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .price-card:hover{
        transition: 0.5s;
        scale: 1.01;
    }
    
    .first{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 30%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .second{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .third{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 70%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .price-card__active button {
        transition: 0.5s;
        color: black;
        background-image: linear-gradient(-235deg, rgb(151, 154, 196) 5%, rgb(46, 20, 152));
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }

.button-div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

.button-buy {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-235deg, rgba(151, 154, 196, 0.767) 5%, rgba(46, 20, 152, 0.807));
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #f3f3f3;
}

.bgCLip{
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-235deg, rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.767) 5%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.807));
    border-radius: 5px;
}
 

.price-div{
    font-family: sans-serif;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.price-div h2{
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.price-div h1{
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема не в стилях, и даже не в react. Как и для обычного js события в react всплывают.

Однако в вашем случае при клике на дочернем элементе у него нет `el.target.id` и статус корректно не устанавливается. Лучше использовать `el.currentTarget.id`

`target` - элемент на котором произошло событие

`currentTarget` - элемент на котором висит событие

```js
const CardPrice = ({name,cost}) => {
  return (
    <span>{name} {cost}</span>
  )
}
const PurchaseButton = () => {
  return (
    <button>Заказать</button>
  )
}

const Card = () => {
  const [divActive, setDivActive] = React.useState("");

  const changeClass = (el) => {
    setDivActive(el.currentTarget.id); 
  }
        
  return(
    <div className='general-div'>
      <div 
        className={`price-card first ${divActive === '1' ? 'price-card__active' : "" } `}
        id='1' 
        onClick={changeClass}
      >
        <CardPrice name={'eco'} cost={'﹩14.99'} />
        <PurchaseButton />
      </div>

      <div 
        className={`price-card second ${divActive === '2' ? 'price-card__active' : "" } `}
        id='2' 
        onClick={changeClass}
      >
        <CardPrice name={'next'} cost={'﹩19.99'} />
        <PurchaseButton />
      </div>

      <div 
        className={`price-card third ${divActive === '3' ? 'price-card__active' : "" } `}
        id='3' 
        onClick={changeClass}
      >
        <CardPrice name={'business'} cost={'﹩24.99'} />
        <PurchaseButton />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Card />
);
```

```css
.general-div{
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .price-card{
        width: 250px;
        height: 350px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(white ,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.806));
        box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        transition: 0.3s;
        border-radius: 8px;
        margin: 10px;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .price-card__active {
        background-image: linear-gradient(-235deg, rgba(151, 154, 196, 0.767) 5%, rgba(46, 20, 152, 0.807));
        border-radius: 12px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        transform:scale(1.04);
        scale: 1.02;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .price-card:hover{
        transition: 0.5s;
        scale: 1.01;
    }
    
    .first{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 30%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .second{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .third{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 70%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .price-card__active button {
        transition: 0.5s;
        color: black;
        background-image: linear-gradient(-235deg, rgb(151, 154, 196) 5%, rgb(46, 20, 152));
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо